# Create a Firestore test db

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Could you tell me how can I maintain a test db with firestore? Few more points about the current implementation of my app.Now I have production DB with ionic 3 app.

1. I have 1 production db
2. I use native fb and g+ logins. So I need to create native apps on firebase console.

**Questions:**

1. Do I need to create a separate project on firebase console to create new test db?
2. If yes then do I need to maintain 2 code bases? That is due to native logins.i.e. I need to add `google-services.json` and `googleservice-info.plist`

Answer (score 3):

You'll indeed need to create separate projects for the test and production environments. But you won't need separate code bases. Have a look at the [documentation on how to set up a single code project for multiple Firebase projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure).

Comment: Most of the areas are cleared with your answer. Thanks.But since this is Ionic 3 project, how can I set up the `google-services.json` and `googleservice-info.plist` files. At this moment we have to put those in the root of the app.like a `package.json` file. But how can I do it when I have multiple files? That is why I thought I need 2 code bases.Your thoughts?

Comment: In the doc where it shows for the native apps. But here hybrid app.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application for a sample of using explicit configuration in your code, which includes a web sample/

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Using that method I can configure the firebase project. But how can I manage the 4 files (`google-services.json` and `googleservice-info.plist`) of the same name on the app root on the web/or Ionic project? I need those file since I'm using native `fb` and `G+` login. Your thoughts?

Comment: There are no files involved in the web snippet in that section. It explicitly specified the values in code, so that you can determine yourself where to get these from. You can either keep all the files in your project in whatever place/form you want, and read from from the files in code, or you can copy the relevant values from the files into your code and select the ones for each target at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.   How do I share my firestore cloud functions?  Do I deploy them to both projects somehow?

Comment: Yes. There is no way to trigger Cloud Functions across projects, so you'll have to deploy them to both. But that also makes sense, since you're going to deploy new updates of the Cloud Functions to the test project first.